# How do I fix a gid on files moved to a new server

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I've copied a folder of data from one linux server to another via a tarball.

The group ids (GIDs) don't match up on the two servers, so I now have files that look like

```
-rw-rw-r--   1 tim  1013   88 2008-11-14 10:18 config
```

There is a mixture of group ownerships in the folder, and I want to keep them owned by different groups on the same server, so I can't just use `chgrp -R`.

How do I change all files/folders with GID 1013 to another group, without affecting other files/folders?

Thanks

Comment: Slightly off topic but...  If you are transferring the files via NFS or Samba there are ways to map the ID's between machines, but they must be set up *before* the transfer begins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo bash -c 'find . -gid 1013 -print0 | xargs -0 chown :1212'
```

This would change them all files owned by group 1013 to gid 1212.  You could add additional options like `-type d` to find to restrict it to something like only directories, see `man find`.

Comment: ta, i always forget about the -0 thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -gid 1013 | xargs chgrp newgroup
```